# use right and left function return to many arguement in excel

Tags: excel-formula

I write a function below in excel to find any comma and if yes then LEFT and LEN . But it return "You've entered too many arguments for this function" . How can I fix this?

```
IF(RIGHT(B2,1)=”,”,LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-1),B2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the double quotes you have there with actual ones, i.e. by deleting and retyping them. It should look like below:

```
IF(RIGHT(B2,1)=",",LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-1),B2)
```

I think the place you copied that from used a different sort of formatting